# Add indexes in list by iterating over rows

Tags: python, pandas, list, conditional-statements, row

I would like to add indexes in list depending on several condition.
With this code I succeeded in adding the series' indexes without any condition.

```
for patient in Series_table.patient_ID.unique(): # For each unique same patient

    for study in Series_table[Series_table['patient_ID']==patient].study_date.unique(): # For each patients and its same unique same studies
        
        ref_series_list = [] # Creating empty list that will contains series of reference
        print(patient)
        print(study)
        print(ref_series_list)
        
        
        # For patient 1 and its same studies, then for patient 1 and its other same studies etc then for patient 2 and its same studies etc)        
        for series in Series_table[(Series_table.patient_ID==patient) & (Series_table.study_date==study)].index:
                      
            print(series)
            ref_series_list.append(series) # We add the series to ref_series_list
            print(ref_series_list)
```

My conditions are the ones following :

```
   
    for series in range(Series_table.ID.shape[0]): # for each series in series table
        print(series)
        for rows in range(ref_image_by_pathology.shape[0]): # for each rows in ref image by pathology
            print(rows)
            
            # If pathology in series tables is different than '' and is the same in Series table and in a row of ref image by pathology
            if Series_table.at[series, 'pathology']!='' and Series_table.at[series, 'pathology'] in ref_image_by_pathology.at[rows, 'pathology']:
            
                # If modality in series tables is different than '' and is the same in Series table and in a row of ref image by pathology
                if Series_table.at[series, 'modality']!='' and Series_table.at[series, 'modality'] in ref_image_by_pathology.at[rows, 'ref_modality']:
                
                    # If acquisition axis in series tables is different than '' and is the same in Series table and in a row of ref image by pathology
                    if Series_table.at[series, 'acquisition_axis']!='' and Series_table.at[series, 'acquisition_axis'] in ref_image_by_pathology.at[rows, 'ref_axis']:
                    
                        # If signal in series tables is different than '' and is the same in Series table and in a row of ref image by pathology
                        if Series_table.at[series, 'signal']!='' and Series_table.at[series, 'signal'] in ref_image_by_pathology.at[rows, 'ref_signal']:
                            
                            # If localization in series tables is different than '' and is common in Series table and in a row of ref image by pathology
                            if Series_table.at[series, 'localization']!= '' and Series_table['localization'].str.contains(ref_image_by_pathology['ref_loc'][rows])[series]:
                
                                 
                                #print(Series_table.series_uid[series])
                                
                                
                                #test.at[series, 'ref_series_id'] = Series_table.ID[series]
                            
                            
                            
                                # 
                                df.at[rows, 'pathology_ID'] = ref_image_by_pathology.ID[rows]
                                
                                df.at[series, 'ref_series_id'] = Series_table.ID[series]
```

If a row in the data frame ref_image_by_pathology matches a row in Series_table (condition of the match : columns pathology  modality, axis, signal in Series_table matches with the same columns in ref_image_by_pathology for the same row and column localization of Series_table contains a pattern of the column localization in ref_image_by_athology for the same row), then I want to add the index or ID (doesn't matter) of Series_table's row that match these condition in the list ref_series_list. The code above works by adding those ID in a column of a df but I would like to add them in the list ref_series_list instead of a df column.

With this code I think I'm close to the answer but I think the problem is where to put "for rows in range(ref_image_by_pathology.shape[0])" because it prints the list with multiple time the same value. I guess the place of this code isn't correct and it iterates more times than I would like to ?

```
for patient in Series_table.patient_ID.unique(): # For each unique same patient

     

    for study in Series_table[Series_table['patient_ID']==patient].study_date.unique(): # For each patients and its same unique same studies
        
        ref_series_list = [] # Creating empty list that will contain series of reference
        print(patient)
        print(study)
        print(ref_series_list)
        
        
        
        # For patient 1 and its same studies, then for patient 1 and its other same studies etc then for patient 2 and its same studies etc)        
        for series in Series_table[(Series_table.patient_ID==patient) & (Series_table.study_date==study)].index:
            print(series)
            #ref_series_list.append(series)
            #print(ref_series_list)
            
            for rows in range(ref_image_by_pathology.shape[0]):
            
                if my conditions
 
                    #print(series)
                    ref_series_list.append(series)
                    print(ref_series_list)
```

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Is it possible that multiple rows satisfy all conditions?

Comment: Hello Tawy, yes it's possible !

Comment: If there is at least one row in df2 that match all condition then I want to import index or ID in a list from my df1 at the row where the condition match with at least one row in df2 !

Answer (score 0):

The data structure is slightly too complicated to easily understand the differences, so I propose to simplify it a bit. Since you want to compute one such `ref_series_list` per combination of (patient,study), let's first assume there is only one patient and one study. Let's also assume that `series_tables` is just a nested list.

```
ref_series_list = []
for series in series_table[patient][study]:
    for rows in range(ref_image_by_pathology.shape[0]):
        if my conditions(rows, series):
            ref_series_list.append(series)
print(ref_series_list)
```

I don't have access to your data, but if multiple rows satisfy all conditions, the value of `series` will be appended to the list each time the conditions evaluate to True.

Then, there are two possibilities depending on what you want:

- Add the series only once if at least one row satisfies all conditions

```
ref_series_list = []
for series in series_table[patient][study]:
    for rows in range(ref_image_by_pathology.shape[0]):
        if my conditions(rows, series):
            ref_series_list.append(series)
            break
print(ref_series_list)
```

- Remember all rows that satisfy the conditions for each series

```
ref_series_list = []
for series in series_table[patient][study]:
    valid_rows = []
    for rows in range(ref_image_by_pathology.shape[0]):
        if my conditions(rows, series):
            valid_rows.append(series)
    ref_series_list.append( [series, valid_rows] )
print(ref_series_list)
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this solves your problem, please accept the answer.